# Eloquent JavaScript:

Tags: javascript

In Chapter 5 of the book Eloquent JavaScript, there's this example that I don't quite understand. It's the noisy function:

```
function noisy(f) {
  return function(arg) {
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    var val = f(arg);
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    return val;
  };
}

noisy(Boolean)(0);
// → calling with 0
// → called with 0 - got false
```

When noisy is called, it has two arguments (Boolean)(0). How does that work? Can you call functions and place arguments in that manner? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's calling 2 functions, noisy, then the anonymous function returned by noisy.

Comment: *"When noisy is called, it has two arguments"* No, it only has one argument. the `(0)` is a separate call of a different function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Boolean` is being passed into `noisy` as the parameter `f`. `noisy` itself returns a function and `0` is being passed into that returned function as the parameter `arg`.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you call functions and place arguments in that manner?

Yes, where a function is returned from initial function

```
function noisy(f) {
  // return anonymous function 
  // `f` : `Boolean` , `arg` : `0`
  return function(arg) {
    // `arg` : `0`
    console.log("calling with", arg);
    // `f` : `Boolean` , `arg` : `0`
    var val = f(arg);
    // `arg` : `0` , `val` : `false`
    console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
    // return `false` : `Boolean(0)`
    return val;
  };
}
// call `noisy` with `Boolean` as parameter,
// where anonymous function returned from `noisy`
// call anonymous function returned from `noisy` with `0`
// as parameter
noisy(Boolean)(0);
```